# Identify AWS IAM user that assumed an IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, assume-role, amazon-guardduty

I'm working on a system that receives new findings from [Amazon GuardDuty](https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/). Most access in our organization is delegated to IAM roles instead of directly to users, so the findings usually result from the actions of assumed roles, and the actor identity of the GuardDuty finding looks something like this:

```
  "resource": {
    "accessKeyDetails": {
      "accessKeyId": "ASIALXUWSRBXSAQZECAY",
      "principalId": "AROACDRML13PHK3X7J1UL:129545928468",
      "userName": "my-permitted-role",
      "userType": "AssumedRole"
    },
    "resourceType": "AccessKey"
  },
```

I know that the `accessKeyId` is created when a security principal performs the `iam:AssumeRole` action. But I can't tell *who* assumed the role in the first place! If it was an IAM user, I want to know the username. Is there a way to programmatically map temporary AWS STS keys (starts with `ASIA`...) back to an original user?

Ideally I'm looking for a method that runs in less than 30 seconds so I can use it as part of my security event pipeline to enrich GuardDuty findings with the missing information.

I've already looked at aws-cli and found `aws cloudtrail lookup-events` but it lacks the ability to narrow the query to a specific accessKeyId so it takes a *loooong* time to run. I've explored the CloudTrail console but it's only about as capable as aws-cli here. I tried saving my CloudTrail logs to S3 and running an Athena query, but that was pretty slow too.

This seems like it would be a common requirement. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: You can query cloudtrial with [athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html) for more sophisticated searches. For ongoing and automated analysis you can also stream CT events to CW Logs, and from there (using subscriptions filters) to Kinesis streams, firehouse, lambda, or event to ES for some fancy realtime analytics dashboards or stats in kibana on the use of roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, aws-cli **can** perform a lookup on the session! Just make sure to specify `ResourceName` as the attribute key in the lookup attributes.

```sh
$ aws cloudtrail lookup-events \
  --lookup-attributes 'AttributeKey=ResourceName,AttributeValue=ASIALXUWSRBXSAQZECAY' \
  --query 'Events[*].Username'

[
    "the.user@example.com"
]
```